# Error in running Homebrew on Mac OS X mavericks

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, homebrew

ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" -e:70: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777 It appears Homebrew is already installed. If your intent is to reinstall you should do the following before running this installer again: rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git && brew cleanup

I have this on my terminal but I cant make use of homebrew. I need to use homebrew to install django pyhton web framework. However I don't seem to get the error here. It says its already installed but none of the brew commands work.

ghochee-macbook-pro:logs streamoid$ brew doctor -bash: brew: command not found <<<<<

Can anyone please help? I also see that there is no .bash_profile file with the PATH variable set, am I looking the right folder and file here?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `/usr/local/bin` isn't on your `$PATH`. You can add it by running the following command in the terminal:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/bin:${PATH}"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Then restart your terminal for the changes to take affect.